# Python: Parse HTML to remove a tag and apply text transformation to all text after the tag

Tags: python, regex, string, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to detect strings that contain the HTML tag `<p><strong class="title"> </strong></p>` and also certain words inside the tag `"shared" OR "amenities"`, and append the word `"shared"` to all comma separated substrings that appear after that tag. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

**Example input:**

```
</strong></p> swimming pool, barbecue <hr /> <p><strong class="title">SHARED CLUB AMENITIES</strong></p> beach, tennis courts <hr /> <p><strong class="title">
```

**Example output:**

```
swimming pool, barbecue, beach shared, tennis courts shared
```

Comment: Head start advice - do not use regex to parse HTML;)

Comment: @liborm you beat me to that comment.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a few differnt libraries for this, common choices are Beautiful Soup, or lxml.  I prefer lxml because most languages have implementations, similar to regex, so it feels like I'll get more mileage out of the investment.

```
from lxml import html

stuff = '</strong></p> swimming pool, barbecue <hr /> <p><strong class="title">SHARED CLUB AMENITIES</strong></p> beach, tennis courts <hr /> <p><strong class="title">'
stuff = html.fromstring(stuff)
ptag  = stuff.xpath('//p/*[contains(text(),"AMENITIES") or contains(text(), "SHARED")]//text()')
print(ptag)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using the code below. Any comments and suggestions welcome!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_to_parse = '</strong></p> swimming pool, barbecue <hr /> <p><strong class="title">SHARED CLUB AMENITIES</strong></p> beach, tennis courts <hr /> <p><strong class="title">'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_to_parse)
html_body = soup('body')[0]

shared_indicator = html_body.find('strong', 'title').get_text()
non_shared_amenities = html_to_parse.split(shared_indicator,1)[0]
non_shared_amenities = (BeautifulSoup(non_shared_amenities, 'html.parser')
         .get_text()
         .strip()
        )
shared_amenities = html_to_parse.split(shared_indicator,1)[1]

shared_amenities_array = (pd.Series(BeautifulSoup(shared_amenities, 'html.parser')
          .get_text()
          .split(','))
          .replace("[^A-Za-z0-9'`]+", " ", regex = True)
          .str.strip()
        .apply(lambda x: "{}{}".format(x, ' shared'))
)

shared_amenities_tagged = ", ".join(shared_amenities_array)

non_shared_amenities + ', ' + shared_amenities_tagged
```